# Node JS Using Bcrypt.Hash- Password does not get hashed on Database

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, react-native, bcrypt

I am try to encrypt password in Node js by use of const bcrypt = require('bcrypt'); but its not hashing. When you try on terminal its hashing but not on database, just posting a plain text that was typed on an input.

Installation and imports

> const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
>
> npm install bcrypt@latest

```
// Sign-up route
app.post('/signup', async (req, res) => {
  const { fullName, email, password } = req.body;

  try {
    // Hash the password before storing it in the database
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

    // Insert user data into the database
    const newUser = { fullName, email, password: hashedPassword };
    db.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', newUser, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Error inserting user:', err);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
        return;
      }

      res.json({ message: 'User registered successfully' });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error hashing password:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
  }
});
```

I am expecting password to hashed, for example password: 123 , this `$2b$10$8hL4zs.XUIXpc6sxf/kfYeKWAcwduZaMlUsZoRz8.cRc5kz9EzEV2` should be posted to database datatype password

Comment: What is the outcome you have, and/or error shown?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone who contributed, I have solved the issue, I clear node js cache and it worked

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps you.

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'password',
  database: 'mydatabase',
});

connection.connect();

app.post('/signup', async (req, res) => {
  const { fullName, email, password } = req.body;

  try {
    // Hash the password before storing it in the database
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

    // Insert user data into the database
    const newUser = { fullName, email, password: hashedPassword };
    connection.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', newUser, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Error inserting user:', err);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
        return;
      }

      res.json({ message: 'User registered successfully' });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error hashing password:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
  }
});

connection.end();
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'password',
  database: 'mydatabase',
});

connection.connect();

app.post('/signup', async (req, res) => {
  const { fullName, email, password } = req.body;

  try {
    // Hash the password before storing it in the database
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

    // Insert user data into the database
    const newUser = { fullName, email, password: hashedPassword };
    connection.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', newUser, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Error inserting user:', err);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
        return;
      }

      res.json({ message: 'User registered successfully' });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error hashing password:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
  }
});

connection.end();
```